# How can I infer the parameter type of a function when I expect the same interface with different generic parameter instantiations?

Tags: f#, refactoring, type-inference, f#-compiler-services

the following code snippet does not compile:

```
[<Interface>]
type IEnvironment<'T> =
    abstract Service: 'T
type IStringEnvironment = IEnvironment<string>
type IIntEnvironment = IEnvironment<int>

module StringEnvironment =

    let get (env: #IStringEnvironment) = env.Service

module IntEnvironment =

    let get (env: #IIntEnvironment) = env.Service

module Composition =

    let get env = 
        let a = StringEnvironment.get env
        let b = IntEnvironment.get env
        a,b
```

I wonder why?

I have almost the same setup in my code, except that i dont use the IEnvironment interface, but I have different "Environments" for different contextx, e.g. i have the following:

```
type ILoggerEnvironment =
    abstract GetLogger: ILogger

[<Interface>]
type IDateTimeEnvironment =
    abstract GetCurrent: DateTime
```

and then the Composition seems to work.

I tried different solutions, writing all functions as inline, but the compiler expects the type of the first usage of env to be the type (even with the prepended #, before the parameter type).

Comment: Good question. This can be done in C#, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work in F#.

Comment: @BrianBerns could you post a c# example where this does work?

Comment: I posted a C# example.

Comment: I reported this as [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/16804) to the F# team, and apparently it's a [known limitation](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1036) of F#.

Answer (score 0):

```
module Composition =

  let get env = 
    let a = StringEnvironment.get env
    let b = IntEnvironment.get env
    a,b
```

an instance of `env` can only be either `IEnvironment<string>` or `IEnvironment<int>` it can not be both at the same time.

As I don't know what is your final goal I cannot give recommendations, but normally if you want to work with different kinds of underling values you can unify them with Discriminated Unions (DU) like this:

```
type Env =
  | Str of IEnvironment<string>
  | Int of IEnvironment<int>
```

Still an instance of `Env` will only be either `Str` or `Int` so the composition you are trying to do does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in C# using type constraints, as follows:

```cs
interface IEnvironment<T>
{
    abstract T Service { get; }
}

interface IStringEnvironment : IEnvironment<string>
{
}

interface IIntEnvironment : IEnvironment<int>
{
}

class Composition()
{
    static (string, int) Get<U>(U env)
        where U : IStringEnvironment, IIntEnvironment   // <-- type constraints
    {
        var a = ((IStringEnvironment) env).Service;
        var b = ((IIntEnvironment) env).Service;
        return (a, b);
    }
}
```

However, the corresponding code in F# doesn't compile:

```ml
[<Interface>]
type IEnvironment<'T> =
    abstract Service: 'T

[<Interface>]
type IStringEnvironment =
    inherit IEnvironment<string>

[<Interface>]
type IIntEnvironment =
    inherit IEnvironment<int>

module StringEnvironment =

    let get (env: IStringEnvironment) = env.Service

module IntEnvironment =

    let get (env: IIntEnvironment) = env.Service

module Composition =

    let get<'U when 'U :> IStringEnvironment and 'U :> IIntEnvironment> (env : 'U) =   // error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch
        let a = StringEnvironment.get env
        let b = IntEnvironment.get env
        a,b
```

I don't know why F# has this limitation. It could be a bug in the compiler.

Using type aliases instead of true interfaces doesn't change the outcome:

```ml
type IStringEnvironment = IEnvironment<string>
type IIntEnvironment = IEnvironment<int>
```